# CreateFileMapping usage in Systools' TStMemoryMappedFile

Tags: delphi, winapi, shared-memory

The Systools library on SourceForge includes a class which is basically a wrapper around a view of a memory-mapped file.  I have a couple of queries about a specific line of its code in its constructor (shown in full at the bottom of this q), namely

```
  FMapObj := CreateFileMapping(THandle($FFFFFFFF), nil, RO3,
                             FMaxHi, FMaxLo, 'STMMFILE1');
```

which is called if the SharedData argument to the constructor is True.  Notice that if SharedData is
true, the FileName argument is ignored, and the name 'STMMFILE1' is used instead.

These are my queries:

Firstly, doesn't the use of the name 'STMMFILE1', which the Systools OLH refers to as "an internal name", mean that all instances of TStMemoryMappedFile running on a system use the same memory-mapped file, so that TStMemoryMappedFile couldn't be used by two pairs of apps which need independent MMFs?  In other words, if I use it to share data between apps A & B, I won't be able to use it on the same machine to share data between apps C & D which is different from A & B's shared data.

Secondly, the MSDN documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx states:

```
"The remainder of the name can contain any character except the backslash character (\)"
```

which prompted me to wonder how CreateFileMapping is used with remote files.  Is that a question of opening a handle to the remote file and passing that as the first argument to CreateFileMapping?      If so, that would seem to be fundamentally incompatible with TStMemoryMappedFile.Create using "THandle($FFFFFFFF)", wouldn't it?

Systools TStMemoryMappedFile constructor:

```
constructor TStMemoryMappedFile.Create(const FileName   : string;      {!!.02}
                                             MaxSize    : Cardinal;
                                             ReadOnly   : Boolean;
                                             SharedData : Boolean);
var
  RO1,
  RO2,
  RO3,
  RO4,
  FHi    : DWORD;
  SetSize: Boolean;
begin
  inherited Create;

  FMutex := CreateMutex(nil, False, nil);
  FSharedData := SharedData;
  if (FSharedData) then
    FHeaderSize := SizeOf(Word) + SizeOf(Cardinal)
  else
    FHeaderSize := 0;

  FReadOnly := ReadOnly;
  if (SharedData) then
    FReadOnly := False;
  if (FReadOnly) then begin
    RO1 := GENERIC_READ;
    RO2 := FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY;
    RO3 := PAGE_READONLY;
    RO4 := FILE_MAP_READ;
    FMaxHi := 0;
    FMaxLo := 0;
  end else begin
    RO1 := GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE;
    RO2 := FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;
    RO3 := PAGE_READWRITE;
    RO4 := FILE_MAP_WRITE;
    FMaxHi := 0;
    FMaxLo := MaxSize;
  end;

  if (not SharedData) then begin
    FHandle := CreateFile(PChar(FileName),
                          RO1,
                          FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                          nil,
                          OPEN_ALWAYS,
                          RO2,
                          0);

    if (FHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
      RaiseStError(EStMMFileError, stscCreateFileFailed);

    {reset FMaxLo if file is read/write and less < FileSize}
    {the result is that the file size cannot be changed but the contents can}
    {still be modified}
    FDataSize := GetFileSize(FHandle, @FHi);
    if (FDataSize <> $FFFFFFFF) then begin
      if (not ReadOnly) and (FDataSize > FMaxLo) then
        FMaxLo := FDataSize;
    end else begin
      CloseHandle(FHandle);
      RaiseStError(EStMMFileError, stscGetSizeFailed);
    end;
  end else
    FDataSize := 0;

  if (not SharedData) then begin
    FMapObj := CreateFileMapping(FHandle, nil, RO3, FMaxHi, FMaxLo, nil);
    SetSize := False;
  end else begin
    if (FMaxLo > (High(Cardinal) - FHeaderSize)) then
      FMaxLo := High(Cardinal) - FHeaderSize
    else
      FMaxLo := FMaxLo + FHeaderSize;
    FMapObj := CreateFileMapping(THandle($FFFFFFFF), nil, RO3,
                                 FMaxHi, FMaxLo, 'STMMFILE1');
    SetSize := (GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS);
  end;

  if (FMapObj = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
    RaiseStError(EStMMFileError, stscFileMappingFailed);

  FBuffer := MapViewOfFile(FMapObj, RO4, 0, 0, FMaxLo);
  if (not Assigned(FBuffer)) then
    RaiseStError(EStMMFileError, stscCreateViewFailed);

  if (SharedData) then begin
    if (SetSize) then
      Move(PByteArray(FBuffer)[SizeOf(Word)-1], FDataSize, SizeOf(Cardinal))
    else begin
      Move(FHeaderSize, PByteArray(FBuffer)[0], SizeOf(Word));
      FDataSize := 0;
      Move(FDataSize, PByteArray(FBuffer)[SizeOf(Word)-1], SizeOf(Cardinal));
    end;
  end;
  {set position to beginning}
  FPos := FHeaderSize;
```

end;

Comment: Strange cast... It is required if you want to write '-1', not required if you do not write the sign, e.g. in hexadecimal. Also the RTL already has `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, but then maybe it didn't back then - don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour switches on `SharedData`. The code you described is the shared case. Backed by swap, and shared by way of the file mapping being named. You ask if all process would share the same mapping. Well yes, that's the whole idea of `SharedData`.

Of course, this design is massively flawed. Suppose I make a pair of apps that share using this component. And you do the same. It's all fine until my apps and your apps appear on the same machine. You can imagine what happens next.

You should probably modify the code to allow the consumer of the class to provide the name.

The issue of remote files is not relevant here because the shared map object is backed by swap file. Your documentation link about object names is not related to file system names. These are kernel objects, under the kernel object namespace. As for remote files, they cannot be mapped reliably.

Comment: "Suppose ..." Yes, that was exactly what I meant by my first query, and it's a relief that you confirm it.  I'll edit the q to make that clearer in a mo.

Comment: Yes, I think they can be mapped. I was too strong in that statement. I wouldn't trust a mapped file that was remote.

Comment: If I were you I'd call the Win32 direct.